# DataTable Invalid JSON response with Angular and Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, datatable

I've been having some problem with datatables on my angular/ruby on rails application, I keep getting this "invalid json response" error, this is my code:

Angular service:

```
  private url: string = "http://localhost:3000/users";

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

angular component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './shared/user.service';
import { User } from "./shared/user";
var $ = require('jquery');
var dt = require('datatables.net')

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $('table').DataTable({ ajax: this.userService.getUsers() });
  }
}
```

And on ruby on rails I have this:

```
 def index
    @users = User.all

    render json: @users
  end
```

This is the JSON I get from that:

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "User 1",
    "cpf_cnpj": "11111111111",
    "rg_ie": null,
    "nascimento": null,
    "email": null,
    "status": null,
    "velocidade_internet": null,
    "sigla": null,
    "funcao": null,
    "setor": null,
    "group_id": null,
    "organization_id": 4,
    "created_at": "2017-06-23T16:45:35.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-06-26T22:34:34.000Z"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "User 2",
    "cpf_cnpj": "123123123123",
    "rg_ie": "123123123",
    "nascimento": "2017-06-23",
    "email": null,
    "status": null,
    "velocidade_internet": null,
    "sigla": null,
    "funcao": null,
    "setor": null,
    "group_id": null,
    "organization_id": 4,
    "created_at": "2017-06-23T16:55:01.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-06-26T22:34:43.000Z"
}]
```

what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi can you share your error log?

Comment: there's no error in my console log